# Get substring from string variable and save to NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsmutablearray, substring

I am new to iOS development and facing some problem. I have a string like this  `M||100|??|L||150|??|S||50.` I want to break the string into chunks and save to array, `e.g M 100` is on 1st index, `L 150` on second index, S 50 on third index.

Comment: i have tried NSArray *subString = [sizeString componentsSeparatedByString:@"||"];
    NSArray *subString1 = [subString componentsSeparatedByString:@"|??|"]; but in substring1 i have all the data on one index

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSString *str = @"M||100|??|L||150|??|S||50";
NSString *stringWithoutBars = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"||" withString:@" "];
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:[stringWithoutBars componentsSeparatedByString:@"|??|"]];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get Array from your string using this code

```
NSString *str = @"M||100|??|L||150|??|S||50";
str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"||" withString:@" "];
NSArray *array = [str componentsSeparatedByString:@"|??|"];
```

this will return your expected result.

Answer (score 0):

```
let str = "M||100|??|L||150|??|S||50"
let array = str.componentsSeparatedByString("|??|")
print(array)
```

result :

```
["M||100", "L||150", "S||50"]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
///First replace "||" with " "

NSString *your_str = @"M||100|??|L||150|??|S||50";
your_str = [your_str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"||" withString:@" "];

///Get array of string

NSArray *arr = [your_str componentsSeparatedByString:@"|??|"];
NSMutableArray *data_arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for(NSString *str in arr)
{
   ///string to data conversion
   NSData *data = [your_str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

   //////// add data to array
   [data_arr addObject: data];
}
NSLog(@"data_arr =%@",data_arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *str = @"M||100|??|L||150|??|S||50";
NSArray *arrt = [str componentsSeparatedByString:@"|??|"];
NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
for (int i = 0; i <= arrt.count - 1; i++) {
    [arr addObject:[[arrt objectAtIndex:i] componentsSeparatedByString:@"||"]];
}
```